# Enable to resolve extra namespaces while marshalling

Tags: namespaces, marshalling

getting extra namespaces i.e :

```
<FedNowOutgoing xmlns="urn:fednow:outgoing:v001" xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02" xmlns:ns3="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.002.001.10">

// Step 1: Create JAXBContext
        //context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.yethi.generatedClassesfromXSD.fedNowMsg.fednowOutgoing.outgoing.v001");
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        //context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.yethi.generatedClassesfromXSD.fedNowPacs008Msg.fednow.incoming.v001");

        // Step 2: Create Marshaller
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        // Step 3: Set Properties (Optional)
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        // Step 4: Marshal Object to XML
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(documentPacs002, writer);

        // Step 5: Print or Save XML
        String xmlString = writer.toString();
        //System.out.println(xmlString);
        writeXmlToFile(xmlString,XSD_OUTPUT_PATH);
```